# How do you insert a PHP constant into a SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a PHP file with my database configuration settings defined as constants, for example:

```
<?php

define(DB_HOST,"localhost");
define(DB_USERNAME,"root");
define(DB_PASSWORD,"password");
define(DB_NAME,"db_users");
define(DB_TABLE_1,"table_1");
define(DB_TABLE_2,"table_2);

?>
```

I obviously include the above file whenever I want to connect to my database..However, when I go to insert the table definition constants into the SQL query (see below) it doesn't seem to work. Do I need to properly escape the constant or concatenate it in some way?

```
$query = "SELECT users FROM DB_TABLE_1";
```

Comment: If PHP only knew the difference between a constant and a read-only variable ...

Answer (score 17):

You'll have to use string concatenation (of any sort).

```
$query = "SELECT users FROM " . DB_TABLE_1;
```

constants will not interpolate into a string as variables can.

One hackish alternative is to use a variable function:

```
$const = 'constant';
$query = "SELECT users FROM {$const('DB_TABLE_1')}";
```

which'll execute the `constant()` function and return the constant's value, but that's generally not a good idea, if only for legibility's sake.

Comment: I stumbled on your answer in regards to using constants in queries and if it were possible (there isn't much out there in regards to this). I think this is rather a very good idea Marc. Sometimes being a bit *hackish* can help prevent injection if going a step or two further. This is similar to something I was working on some time ago and had some promising results.

Answer (score 5):

Just put it outside the quotes and it should work fine:

```
$query = "SELECT users FROM ".DB_TABLE_1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found two ways.

1.-

```
define("VALUE1", "someValue");
$query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE `Column` /*=" . VALUE1 . "*/";
```

2.-

```
define("VALUE1", "someValue");
define("VALUE2", "otherValue");
$query = "INSERT INTO TABLE (`Column1`, `Column2`) VALUES (" . VALUE1 . ", " . VALUE2 . ")";
```

The backticks (``) I use because I'm using phpmyadmin, you might not need them.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is easier:

```
$query = "SELECT users FROM '.DB_TABLE_1.'";
```

when using multiple tables:

```
$query = "SELECT TB_1.users, TB_2.names FROM '.TB_1.'
          INNER JOIN '.TB_2.' 
          ON x=y";
```

Also, this is better:

```
define("DB_HOST","localhost");
```