# PHP SELECT WHERE array_intersect

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Need to run a mysql SELECT through PHP where two arrays equal one another.

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM around WHERE 'array_intersect($ar1, $ar2)'";
 $resultsd = $conn->query($sql);
 foreach($resultsd as $rowd) {

 $sword[] = $rowd['TIM'];
 }
```

After the match is found, need to pull from that particular row in mysql. This needs to be in PHP.

Arrays are from:

```
  $ar1 = array();
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM blc WHERE ffv='$safe_username'";
  $results = $conn->query($sql);
  foreach($results as $row) {  
  $ar1[] = $row['vvvs'];
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Imitate array\_intersect in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813246/imitate-array-intersect-in-mysql)

Comment: The main question here is about PHP. What you have just linked has nothing to do with PHP. Please do not cause any confusion here.

Comment: I'm not @TebTheestatebook. You're asking if you can use a PHP function in a MySQL statement. The answer is *no*. But you can imitate it with the link provided. If your question is different than that you need to clear things up.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Actually, you can run a function inside a query; it's just very tricky *Sam* ;-)

Comment: How Fred? For some reason Jay wants to make incorrect generalizations.

Comment: I did say "a" function, just maybe not "that" function. If you use `{}` and use a constant.

Comment: wish I understood what that meant.

Comment: Here's an example of using a constant http://stackoverflow.com/a/8883920/ you may be able to play around with that. @JayBlanchard *cool eh Sam?*

Comment: Is it possible to only display when '.TB_1.' = INNER JOIN '.TB_2.'?

Comment: Of course *Ralph*, but I think that the generalization is warranted because the use of a PHP function in a query statement throws several red flags including concerns about logic, code organization, SQL injection. Thoughts @Fred-ii-

Comment: *Aye,* couldn't agree with ye more *Sam, me matey!* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: Just tell me, is it possible to use string concentration and compare them SELECT * WHERE table like '.TB_1.' =  INNER JOIN '.TB_2.'

Comment: What are `TB_1` and `TB_2`?

Comment: Jay they are arrays defined by something like: define("TB_1", $ar1 );

Comment: Can you modify your question to add the code for the arrays?

Comment: Sidenote: I thought the question was rather interesting and feel it didn't deserve the negative votes and is worthy of Stack's questions/answers archive.

Comment: You're welcome Teb; *cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given two arrays and wanting to perform a query for the intersection of those arrays:

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `around` WHERE `foo` IN ('" . implode("','", $result) . "')";
```

This results in the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `around` WHERE `foo` IN ('green','red')
```

The intersection happens outside of the query because there still is stuff to do with the data before it is usable in a query. Actually I would be neater and do this:

```
$results = "'" . implode("','", $result) . "'";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `around` WHERE `foo` IN ({$results})";
```

Comment: Hey @Fred -ii- cast your eye on this and see if you'd make improvements.

Comment: *Hm...* interesting Sam; good show 'ol chap! Seems all good to *moi* ;-)